# Append original headers on redirect with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, redirect, header, asihttprequest

i'm accessing an API over HTTP and use ASIHTTPRequest. To access the API I have to send additional headers, which i add with the following:

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Access-Key" value:@"1234"];
```

These headers have to be sent with every request. When I get redirected these headers get lost so i'd like to set them again. Is there any possibility to set them again, before the redirect request is beeing performed?

When I implement the *- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request willRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)newURL* Method, the request gets cancelled after this delegate function is called. Is it a bug? I'm using the version v1.8.1-8 2011-06-05.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve the Problem. IMO the naming of the method is a bit confusing. When you implement `- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request willRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)newURL` the Method is called, but after the request isn't redirected as I asumed. You have to redirect the request by yourself:

```
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request willRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)newURL {
    // modify request here, e.g. set request headers again...
    [request redirectToURL:newURL];
}
```

Thanks for reading my question, hope this helps anyone else.